# Calculate CPU load in nodejs with windows support

Tags: node.js

How to calculate current CPU load in nodejs? I tried os module of nodejs, but as per [this](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_loadavg) documentation, it will return [0,0,0] if platform is windows.

Is there any alternative to calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-cpu
(support for Windows 7 / 8 / Server 2008)

Comment: I tried it but with pm2 it is flashing another console, and I can't constantly monitor using this module.